# Objective-C dispatch_after sometimes executes earlier than specified

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, queue, grand-central-dispatch

I have some Objective-C code that I need to trigger after a specified time. I have been using the code below, and 95% of the time, it works great. However, sometimes the code will execute *really* early. Like 5 seconds instead of 60 seconds. It is completely inconsistent and I can't make it happen on purpose. Any idea what could cause this?

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(60 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //do code stuff here
});
```

Comment: Can you include the backtrace from the thread that runs the block? Maybe there's something in there.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem and my solution is:

```
dispatch_time_t delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    // YOUR CODE HERE
});
```

Hope this will work for you as well.